# How do I access an environment variable in a puppet manifest?

Tags: puppet

How do I access an environment variable (from the puppet daemon's environment) in a puppet manifest?

Comment: Do you mean a variable generated by facter?

Comment: I mean the bash environment variables like $PATH and $USER.

Answer (score 8):

I think we need more informations on what you are trying to achieve...
Facter exposes by default FACTER_ environment variables :

https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/faq.html#can-i-access-environment-variables-with-facter

```
 $ FACTER_FOO="bar" 
 $ export FACTER_FOO
 $ facter | grep 'foo'
   foo => bar
```

But for $PATH or $USER... Why not tells puppet to use a given path or a user (for an exec ?) explicitly ?

Comment: It's very ordinary to control an interpreter with environment variables, for a variety of reasons... especially if you think about sometimes running puppet as an interpreter (in the #! line?) instead of a daemon...

Comment: Excellent answer. I wasted a lot of time not noticing that all Facter variables have lowercase names even if the environment variable has an uppercase name. Everybody pay close attention to the example jnrg gives.

Comment: there is broken link

Comment: According to the new doc: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/core_facts.html the path and identity are returning the data the OP requested.

Answer (score 7):

You'd need to use a server side function for this if you want the puppetmaster's environment.  Since facter gets you client facts.

$RUBYLIB/puppet/parser/functions/env.rb:

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
  newfunction(:env) do |args|
    variable = args[0]
    ENV[variable]
  end
end
```

Use it in your manifests like:

```
$blah = env("PATH")
```

Answer (score 6):

From what I can tell Puppet runs without any Bash environment variables. It seems to get all its environment from Facter. There is a script [here](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Environment_Variables_Patterns) to import your regular envvars as Facter envvars.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. Could you please update the answer accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

In Puppet enterprise 2.5.1 you can access it via /etc/env.

Also check whether you have the correct environment defined in your `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf` -- it should look something like this:

```
[production]
  modulepath = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environments/production/modules:/opt/puppet/share/puppet/modules
  manifest   = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/environments/production/manifests/site.pp
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is a bit disappointing: You can't (unless you enhance Puppet or Facter).
I recently wrote a short blog post about this topic:
[Accessing environment variables within Puppet](http://www.xenuser.org/open-source-development/using-environment-variables-in-puppet/)

A short summary: Facter is running on every Puppet agent system. Simply enhance Facter to collect all environment variables and then you can access them within Puppet manifests.

Hope that helps!